# What is the difference between "deploy" & "run" goal in maven tomcat plugin

Tags: maven, tomcat, plugins

The question is simple as above, what is the difference between "deploy" & "run" goal  in maven tomcat plugin?

`mvn help:describe -Dplugin=tomcat7` provides the list of goals available for this plugin. But I do not get the what is the difference between them.

---

More information

```
> mvn help:describe -Dplugin=tomcat7

tomcat7:deploy
  Description: Deploy a WAR to Tomcat.

tomcat7:run
  Description: Runs the current project as a dynamic web application using an
    embedded Tomcat server.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `deploy` goal will deploy your `war` to a Tomcat server. That means that it will copy the files and register the web application in the Tomcat server you're deploying to. The `run` goal will start an in-process Tomcat server in which your application will run.

Comment: So, that means I can deploy as many as webapp I want, but can run only one. Right?

Comment: Well, look at it this way: With `deploy`, you can deploy many applications to the same (or different) Tomcat servers. With `run`, you're essentially running one Tomcat per application.